# Two drivers for same device in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers

I am a beginner. Is it possible to have two drivers for same device in Ubuntu?

Example: Two drivers for one graphic card.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify. You you want to use two drivers for one Graphic Card or one USB Device? OR one driver for a Grapic Card an an USB-Device? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a device can only use one driver. Maybe you can install two drivers, but just one driver will be used for the device.
Some drivers do an uninstall of other drivers while your are installing them or give you an error, that another driver is installed and causing problems.