# Use different drivers for two identical peripherals

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, virtualbox

I have two NICs that are the same type (plain old VirtualBox NICs).  Is it possible to use a different driver for each one?

From what I've seen when I load a module it picks up on all the supported NICs and runs with them.  I know I can blacklist a driver so that it doesn't load at all, but what I want to do is effectively blacklist a driver for a single peripheral and manually specify the driver that I do want to load.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: [Related](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272655/two-drivers-for-same-device-in-ubuntu), but not at all what I'm after